# Recognised file types for image preview?

Tags: svg, ckan

Is it possible to add additional file types to be recognised as images and thus trigger automatic creation of an image view when a resource is uploaded?

SVG files will preview in CKAN, but  we have to manually add the image view e.g.
https://datastore.landcareresearch.co.nz/dataset/novel-yeasts-from-new-zealand-forests/resource/3812ee6b-dd45-45c9-b425-6a18375e5727

With text (for example) we can specify file format extensions to recognise as text and automatically create a text preview (ckan.preview.text_formats...).  Is there an equivalent for images?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It would only be possible by modifying the source code for your instance:
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckanext/imageview/plugin.py#L9

Seems like a great idea to have the image view on a par with the text view in this regard, so I made a pull request:
https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3380

Comment: PR is now merged so should make it into an upcoming CKAN release: https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3380

Comment: Thanks @Matt-Fullerton